# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _fblas, when running Python from Visual Studio C# via CFFI

Tags: c#, python-3.x, scipy, blas, python-cffi

I'm trying to run an image processing Python script from Visual Studio C# using CFFI.
I have compiled the Python script `feature-extraction.py` into the DLL `feature-extraction.dll`, which I wrap into C# code via P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport(@"..\..\feature-extraction.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void GetFeatures(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path,
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[] featureNames, 
            [In, Out] float[] featureValues);
```

When calling `GetFeatures(path, names, values)`, I get the following error:
[image]

I reinstalled `scikit-image` and `scipy` (`pip install scikit-image`, `pip install scipy`), and also added the Pythonwin and Python's win32\lib folders to PATH, but I still have this issue.
I tried `pip install blas`, `pip install _fblas`, but it says `No matching distribution for blas`.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there a specific `blas` package that I need to install, in addition to `scipy`?
Thanks in advance!

LE: I can run `feature-extraction.py` successfully from anaconda3 prompt, which makes me think there is some issue with the runtime environment when running from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I reinstalled `SciPy` from sources using the instructions in https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/windows.html. Turns out, I had to first install `OpenBLAS`, and then `Scipy`.